# mysql foreign key is not working

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

i am trying to set foreign key constraint on my table so that the row will be deleted automatically on deleting the primary key

the primary table is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_users` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`username` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`user_role` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'staff',
`user_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'staff name',
`user_email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
`user_phone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`user_login_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

and the foreign key table is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_user_meta` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`staff_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`dep_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

i used the following query to set foreign key

```
alter table tbl_user_meta add foreign key('user_id') references tbl_users('user_id') on     delete cascade;
```

the query is ok but foreign key constraint is not working
please help me

i am using wamp server on windows with mysql 5.6.12

Comment: Change your engine to InnoDB that supports foreign keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreign key constraints are not supported in MyISAM Engine.

> [Foreign Key Differences](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html)
>   The InnoDB storage engine supports checking of foreign key
>   constraints, including CASCADE, ON DELETE, and ON UPDATE. See Section
>   14.2.3.4, “InnoDB and FOREIGN KEY Constraints”.
>   **For storage engines other than InnoDB, MySQL Server parses the FOREIGN
>   KEY syntax in CREATE TABLE statements, but does not use or store it.**

To be able to use FK constraints you have to use **InnoDB** engine.

You can change the engine for your tables this way

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_users ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE tbl_user_meta ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

**UPDATE** You can produce `ALTER TABLE` statements for all your tables with this query

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(
  'ALTER TABLE `', table_name, '` ENGINE=InnoDB') SEPARATOR ';\n') 
  FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE table_schema = SCHEMA()
   AND ENGINE = 'MyISAM';
```

and then just copy and execute them

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/464956/5)** demo

Comment: then which engine i should use...it is set by default

Comment: You should use InnoDB

Comment: all my tables are now in MyISAM.how can i convert them to innodb.There is a lot of tables in my database

Comment: thank you so much...is there any security issues for using innodb?

Comment: You're quite welcome :). I don't quite understand what exactly you mean by *security issues for using innodb*, but InnoDB now is the default and the most advanced engine. And if you need FK and transactional support it's the only option. More over Oracle puts a lot of resources to push it forward unlike MyISAM which eventually will be deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Use INNODB. 
 
see details here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html.